# Behave Python: How to create separate variable file to use as input parameter

Tags: python

I am new to behave-python and I am trying to create a separate variable file as input to run various feature tests instead of defining them at command line:

Command Line Example:

> python -m behave -D ip=1.2.3.4 -D user= -D password= -D endpoint=0x41 -D host=2.3.4.5 -D host_username=root -D host_password=pass1234 -D slot=2 -D adapter_fam=adapt1 -i "myfeat0.feature"

And if I have to run next feature, I have to declare the following

> python -m behave -D ip=1.2.3.4 -D user= -D password= -D endpoint=0x51 -D host=2.3.4.5 -D host_username=root -D host_password=pass1234 -D slot=2 -D adapter_fam=adapt2 -i "myfeat1.feature"

So I was wondering if there is another option to put all these parameters into something like a variable file and reference it at command line instead of explicitly defined as above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [docs on `userdata_defines` in config files](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/behave.html#configuration-files)

Otherwise, assuming you're using Linux, then you can `source` variables into the session

Example

```
$ cat config
FOO=bar
```

```
$ echo $FOO
$ source config
$ echo $FOO
bar
```

---

So, you'd have something like `python -m behave -D foo=$FOO` after sourcing the file